# Connecting OHIF viewer to Orthanc Pacs Server

Tags: javascript, python

Orthanc is running on port 8042.

I have run the following commands to view the images in my Orthanc pacs, through the OHIF viewer which is running on port 3000 but its returning a black screen:

```
yarn config set workspaces-experimental true
yarn install
yarn run dev:orthanc
```

After running the above code I am expecting OHIF to render on port 3000 showing a list of images which are in my Orthanc Pacs, but I am only receiving a black screen. How can I solve this? Are there any further configurations which need to be made?

Comment: you may need to run `yarn orthanc:up` to start orthanc before you run `yarn dev:orthanc`